# does the subgraph of a measurable function is measurable set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function
how do I show that $A = \{(x,y) : y \leq f(x) \}$ is a measurable set in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start by looking at the set $\{(x,y) : y < f(x)\}$ instead.

1. If $f = \chi_A$ is the indicator of a measurable set, then $\{y < f(x)\}$ is the set $A \times (-\infty,1) \cup (\mathbb R \setminus A) \times (-\infty,0)$ which is measurable.
2. If $f_n$ is a sequence of functions that increases to $f$, then $\{y < f(x)\} = \bigcup_n \{y < f_n(x)\}$.
3. $\displaystyle \{y \le f(x)\} = \bigcap_k \left\{y < f(x) + \frac 1k\right\}.$

These three facts put together give you the measurability of the subgraph of nonnegative measurable functions via the usual limiting processes.

From there you can work to establish measurability for arbitrary functions by splitting into positive and negative parts.